# Correct teardown sequence for Kubernetes infrastructure components

Tags: kubernetes, order-of-execution, teardown

In order to deploy my k8s cluster I `kubectl apply -f folder-of-yamls/`

And it seems that the order of execution is important.
One approach I've seen is to prefix `001-namespace.yaml` `002-secrets.yaml` etc. to create an ordering.

To tear down, if I `kubectl delete -f folder-of-yamls/`, can I simply reverse the order or must I manually create a sequence?

Comment: fyi the [order helm installs](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-3.4/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go#L31) and [uninstalls](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-3.4/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go#L71)

Comment: IME the order of execution isn't that important, but there's also an assumption that it's okay if a pod crashes and restarts if something it calls out to isn't available.  If there are object-level dependencies (a Pod gets a value from a ConfigMap) `kubectl delete -f folder/` should clean everything up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of deletion shouldn't matter to much, as mentioned by David Maze in comments, `kubectl delete -f folder/` will clean up everything correctly, however there might be some issues when you delete objects that are dependent from other. For example `PVC` should be deleted before `PV` (PV will take forever to be deleted) but kubernetes should take care of that if everything is present in directory you are deleting yamls from.